# How to make my Java application automatically reconnect with MySQL DB after internet connectivity restored

Tags: java, mysql

I'm connecting to MySQL Database running in a server from a Java Swing desktop application. When the desktop application internet connectivity gets interrupted, I always have to close the application and open it again to connect with the database. Is there a method that I can use to make my application automatically connect to the Database? I use the following code to connect to the DB.

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");  
Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection(  
"jdbc:mysql://<ServerIP>:3306/store","root","XXXXXX");  
Statement stmt=con.createStatement();
```

Comment: I would recommend using a framework to manage that for you.  Spring/Springboot and Hibernate are the usually the gotos.

Comment: Perhaps use an ScheduledExecutorService thread to check the DB Connection at a specific interval. If the connection is not there then reopen the connection.